# Copy Directory to SMB Share Through Terminal

Tags: tasker, terminal, nandroid

On Rooted Android 4.1, I have it set up to be able to make NAndroid backups through terminal emulator.

What I hope to do is schedule a Tasker job to create a NAndroid backup and then copy/move it across wifi to my PC, so I can schedule it to run once a week in the middle of the night.

I know MV will move files/directories, but I'm not sure how to specify the network share as the destination.

I'll keep looking into it, but if anyone has already solved this one I would love to hear about it!

Answer (score 0):

To gain that possibility, you would need to mount the remote (PC) drive on your Android device. This could e.g. be done using [CifsManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.plattner.cifsmanager) or [Mount Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twimager.cifsmanager). The latter even offers a *Tasker* plugin, which would fit your wanted feature of being able to handle things directly from *Tasker*. And if you have trouble with it, you'll find its author/dev here at ASE, I'd say from the name :)